# Cropping an Image In The Browser Automatically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I crop an image automatically through the upload process? Is there php function to do that?

I want my webpage to display the images with the same dimension from various dimension of the original images by cropping it.

Or any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this as `max_size.php`

```
<?php header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
function resampleimage($maxsize, $sourcefile, $imgcomp=0){
$g_imgcomp=100-$imgcomp;
    if(file_exists($sourcefile)){
    $g_is=getimagesize($sourcefile);
        if($g_is[0] <= $maxsize && $g_is[1] <= $maxsize){
            $new_width=$g_is[0];
            $new_height=$g_is[1];
        } else {
            $w_adjust = ($maxsize / $g_is[0]);
            $h_adjust = ($maxsize / $g_is[1]);
      if($w_adjust <= $h_adjust){
          $new_width=($g_is[0]*$w_adjust);
          $new_height=($g_is[1]*$w_adjust);
      } else {
          $new_width=($g_is[0]*$h_adjust);
          $new_height=($g_is[1]*$h_adjust);
      }
    }
    $image_type = strtolower(strrchr($sourcefile, "."));

    switch($image_type) {
      case '.jpg':
         $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);
         break;
      case '.jpeg':
         $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);
         break;
      case '.png':
         $img_src = imagecreatefrompng($sourcefile);
         break;
      case '.gif':
         $img_src = imagecreatefromgif($sourcefile);
         break;
      default:
         echo("Error Invalid Image Type");
         die;
         break;
   }
  $img_dst=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
  imagecopyresampled($img_dst, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $g_is[0], $g_is[1]);
  imagejpeg($img_dst);
  imagedestroy($img_dst);
  return true;
  } else {
  return false;
  }
}
resampleimage($_GET['maxsize'], $_GET['source']);
?>
```

In the page where you have image

```
<img id="img" src="max_size.php?maxsize=152&source=[some image path]" />
```

Comment: Hmm...Thx for fast response!

I think the script above just creating the thumbnail of the image
with the same dimension for both height and width. However, it's great idea. :-)

Comment: Your first statement is correct. It is creating thumbnail right but not of same width and height..Its like it will create thumb but in same ratio of the source only max size will be for width in landscape and in portrait  max size will be for height...Also you wanted something to be created automatically...So can be the way or otherwise many cropping scripts are available for jquery but not automatic...

Comment: Most of the available cropping script seems require us to cropping the image manually. I think there are other ways to do this in the "sky".

Answer (score 2):

Automatic cropping would be difficult without knowing where is the subject. Maybe you can try to get an inner centered rectangle, like in the picture:

[image: Inner rectangle picture shows a rectangle within another one]

The first thing to do is **find the original image dimensions and file type**. You should not trust the image extension and instead use [`getimagesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) for that. Despite the name `getimagesize` not only returns the size but also the file type.

```
//width is at index 0, height at index 1, mime type at ['mime'] key
$original = getimagesize($filename);
```

Then you should **build an internal PHP data structure to hold the source image** in memory, so you can manipulate it, using [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) or [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) or [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php), depending on the image type. For instance:

```
$srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

Next, you should **allocate another data structure to hold the destination image**. In this case we don't have an image to start with, so I allocate an empty image.

```
$dstImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
```

Next, you should **copy a portion of the original image to the destination image**. If you don't want to resize, use [`imagecopy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php), otherwise if you want to crop and resize you can consider [`imagecopyresampled`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

```
imagecopy(dstImage, $srcImage, 0, 0, $srcX, $srcY, $srcW, $srcH);
```

Where $srcX is the starting X point in the source image, $srcY the starting Y point, $srcW the width to copy from the starting X point, $srcH the height of the area to be copied.

Finally you can either **save your image** with:

```
imagejpeg($this->dstImage, $filename, 90);
```

or you can **output it to the browser** with:

```
imagejpeg($this->dstImage);
```

If you save the image you've to think in which directory to save it, if you have lots of images (thousands or more), think a way to split them in multiple subdirectory.

If you save the original image, never save images with extensions not in your list of allowed extension or it will be a **huge security hole** in which the attacker can send and execute any PHP code to your site.

Based on the concepts described I wrote a small class:

```
class ImageCrop {

    //Image resources
    private $srcImage, $dstImage;

    //original width and height
    private $width, $height;

    /**
    * Read an image from disk.
    * @return true in case of success, false otherwise.
    */
    public function openImage($filename) {
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            return false;
        }
        $original = getimagesize($filename);
        switch ($original['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $this->srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $this->srcImage = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $this->srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        $this->width = $original[0];
        $this->height = $original[1];
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * Crop an image to the new specified dimension trying to get an 
    * internal rectangle of the original image. No crop is done if the 
    * original dimension is already smaller than $newWidth or $newHeight.
    */
    public function crop($newWidth, $newHeight) {
        $this->dstImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        $srcX = $srcY;
        $srcW = $this->width;
        $srcH = $this->height;
        $extraWidth = $this->width - $newWidth;
        if ($extraWidth > 0) {
            $srcX = $extraWidth / 2;        
        }
        $extraHeight = $this->height - $newHeight;
        if ($extraHeight > 0) {
            $srcY = $extraHeight / 2;
        }
        imagecopy($this->dstImage, $this->srcImage, 0, 0, 
            $srcX, $srcY, $srcW, $srcH);
    }

    /**
     * Save the destination image, the crop function should have been 
     * called already.
     */
    public function save($filename) {
        imagejpeg($this->dstImage, $filename, 90);
    }

    /**
    * Output the destination image to the browser.
    */
    public function output() {
        imagejpeg($this->dstImage);
    }

}
```

Save the class in ImageCrop.php, sample usage:

```
require_once 'ImageCrop.php';

$imageCrop = new ImageCrop();
if ($imageCrop->openImage('big.jpg')) {
    $imageCrop->crop(200, 300); //newWidth, newHeight
    $imageCrop->save('small.jpg');
}
```

or, to send the output directly to the browser, use `$imageCrop->output();`.

Comment: Thx for editing my post, i'm sorry for my bad english. :-)

No, I don't want to resize it, I just want to crop it. So when a user upload an image that exceeds the dimensions that I allowed, it will be cropped automatically. Would you tell me the idea about "inner rectangle"? thx in advanced.

Comment: Updated my post, now I crop an inner centered rectangle.

Comment: Ok Stivlo. This seems very interesting, let me try it for a while. I will send you back some responses latter.

Comment: Hi, here is my promise. Stivlo.. good job! I've been tested your class and it work fine. Thx a lot. Your answer is very good because it is accompanied with the concept and direct implementation. I will vote your answer. :-)

Comment: I appreciate your code stivlo and chemistry between you guys Philips Tel and stivlo...but only problem I see with this code is you have to give width and height to crop the real image, so the generated image could be distorted while mine you have to give maximum size (width or height) i.e. if your image container is portrait give width or if it is landscape give height. That's it.....

Comment: @Wazzzy since I'm not scaling, but cropping, there is no way to distort the image, is a pixel by pixel copy. The problem could be, instead to miss the subject, especially if the original image is much bigger than the cropped area, in which case it would be probably better to combine scaling and cropping.