# How to crop images automatically in the browser using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, crop

Someone posted a great way to [crop images via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845044/cropping-an-image-in-the-browser-automatically). I implemented it to crop 12 photos in rectangulars:

**PHP:**

```
$count=count( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] );

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$image=$_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"][$i];
$imagename=$_FILES['photo']["name"][$i];
move_uploaded_file($image,'images/'.$imagename);
$imglocation='images/'.$imagename;

$sizes = getimagesize($imglocation);
$imgwidth = $sizes[0];
$imgheight = $sizes[1];

if($imgwidth<$imgheight){
    $imgheight=$imgwidth;
}
elseif($imgheight<$imgwidth){
    $imgwidth=$imgheight;
}

$j=$i+1;

$imageCrop = new ImageCrop();
if ($imageCrop->openImage($imglocation)) {
    $imageCrop->crop($imgwidth, $imgheight); //newWidth, newHeight
    $imageCrop->save('data'.$j.'.png');
}
}
```

Now I want to preview the cropped image in the browser. Since I will be using sessions, I don't want to use the saved images on the server, it would be vulnerable to work with it in javascript. Is there a way to get the uploaded files and crop them the same way in javascript?

Comment: http://jcrop.org/

Comment: Automatically. No user interface